# Plotting Fisher Information using PennyLane

Tags: pennylane, quantum-fisher-information, postselection

I made 2-qubit based circuit with post-selection method.

Post-selection method is, Let
$$
K =  \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{1-\gamma} & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\,.  
$$

Then,
$$ \rho_{\text{post-selection}}
=
\frac{(K \otimes K) \rho (K^{\dagger} \otimes K ^{\dagger})}
{Tr\big[(K \otimes K) \rho (K^{\dagger} \otimes K ^{\dagger})\big]}
\,.$$

With the above density matrix, I calculated Classical Fisher Information with PennyLane's `qml.qinfo.classical_fisher` for the selected sweeping boundary 0 ~ 3$\pi$. Using that data, I created a plot for 3 cases of $\gamma = \{0.3, 0.4, 0.7\}$ using `plt.plot`

[image]

However, the result of 3-gamma with the selected sweeping area shows a distorted shape whereas it should be smooth. I noticed significant distortion at Time: around 5~

Can anybody help with this? Thanks in advance

```
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, Latex

import numpy as np_
import scipy as sp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 2-qubit
dev = qml.device('default.mixed', wires= 2)

# == Hamiltonian setup == 
coeffs = [1]
obs = [qml.PauliZ(0) @ qml.PauliZ(1)]

hamiltonian = qml.Hamiltonian(coeffs, obs)

Tau_global, Phi_global = np.zeros(3), 0
Gamma_ps_global = 0

# 1-layer
@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit_alt(phi_in):
    global Tau_global, Phi_global
    
    theta_init, tau_1, tau_2,  = [1e-3]*3
    phi = phi_in
    
    # Stage_1: RY for pi/2
    qml.RY(np.pi/2, wires=0)
    qml.RY(np.pi/2, wires=1)
    
    # Stage_2: Entangler    
    qml.ApproxTimeEvolution(hamiltonian, -tau_1/2, 1)
    
    qml.RX(theta_init, wires = 0)    
    qml.RX(theta_init, wires = 1)    

    qml.RY(-np.pi/2, wires = 0)    
    qml.RY(-np.pi/2, wires = 1)   

    qml.ApproxTimeEvolution(hamiltonian, -tau_2/2, 1)

    qml.RY(np.pi/2, wires = 0)    
    qml.RY(np.pi/2, wires = 1) 
    
    # Stage_3: Accumulator
    qml.ApproxTimeEvolution(hamiltonian, -phi/2, 1)
    
    
    qml.RY(-np.pi/2, wires=0)
    qml.RY(-np.pi/2, wires=1)
    
    return qml.density_matrix(wires=[0, 1])

fig, ax = qml.draw_mpl(circuit_alt)(0)


@qml.qnode(dev)
def Post_selection_alt(phi):
    global Gamma_ps_global
    Gamma_ps = Gamma_ps_global
        
    # Get density matrix from circuit_alt
    density_matrix = np.zeros((4, 4), dtype=np.complex128)
    density_matrix = circuit_alt(phi)
    
    qml.QubitDensityMatrix(density_matrix, wires=[0, 1])
    
    # Kraus operator for 2*2 matrix
    K = np.array([ [np.sqrt(1 - Gamma_ps), 0], [0, 1] ])
    K_H = K.conj().T
    
    Numerator = sp.linalg.kron(K, K) @ density_matrix @ sp.linalg.kron(K_H, K_H)
    Denominator = np.trace(sp.linalg.kron(K, K) @ density_matrix @ sp.linalg.kron(K_H, K_H))
    
    rho_ps = Numerator / Denominator
    
    qml.QubitDensityMatrix(rho_ps, wires=[0, 1])
    
    return qml.density_matrix(wires=[0, 1])


def Sweep(Sweep_bound, Gamma_ps_in):
    
    PHI = np.arange(Sweep_bound[0], Sweep_bound[1], Sweep_bound[2]).reshape(-1, 1)
    
    Data = np.zeros((len(PHI), 1 + len(Gamma_ps_in)))
    
    Data[:, 0] = PHI.squeeze()
    
    GAMMA_INDEX_IN_DATA = 1
    
    global Gamma_ps_global
    
    
    for Gamma_index in range(len(Gamma_ps_in)):
        Gamma_ps_global = Gamma_ps_in[Gamma_index]
        
        for i in range(len(PHI)):
            Data[i][Gamma_index + GAMMA_INDEX_IN_DATA] = qml.qinfo.classical_fisher(Post_selection_alt)(PHI[i])
        

    return Data


Sweep_data = np_.array([1e-4, np.pi * 3 + 1e-4, np.pi/(25*2)])
Gamma_ps_desired = 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.8

Result = Sweep(Sweep_data, Gamma_ps_desired)


plt.plot(Result[:,0], Result[:,1], label = 0.3)
plt.plot(Result[:,0], Result[:,2], label = 0.4)
plt.plot(Result[:,0], Result[:,3], label = 0.7)

plt.title('CFI by gamma')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('CFI')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

Comment: Not sure what's happening with your state over time, but it is possible the that QFI becomes discontinuous and would be smoothened by instead using the Bures metric (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.052320). There's probably some term where $\partial p(\eta)/\partial \theta\approx 0$ and then $p(\eta)\to 0$ so that $(\partial p(\eta)/\partial \theta)^2/p(\eta)$ quickly moves away from 0